# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a nonnegative symmetric matrix, is $-\lambda$ also an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is a non-negative, symmetric matrix, is it necessarily the case that the set of all eigenvalues of $A$ can be written $L = \{ \pm\lambda_0, \pm\lambda_1,\cdots\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

$1$ is an eigenvalue of $I$ (i.e. the identity matrix), but $-1$ is not.

If you want a concrete example, take the non-negative symmetric $1\times 1$ matrix $[1]$ which has one eigenvalue, $\lambda=1$.

In fact, if your definition of "nonnegative" is

> A matrix $A$ is nonnegative if $\langle Ax, x\rangle \geq 0$ for all vectors $x$.

then the only way $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ are both eigenvalues is if $\lambda = 0$.

This is because if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue and $x\neq0$ is it's eigenvector, then $$\langle Ax, x\rangle = \mu \|x\|^2 \geq 0$$

this means that if $\lambda, -\lambda$ are both eigenvalues, then $\lambda\geq0$ and $-\lambda\geq0$ which means $0\leq \lambda\leq 0$ and $\lambda = 0$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I got back on to edit my question since I realized I messed it up. $A$ is supposed to have zero diagonal. The other question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369955/if-lambda-is-an-eigenvalue-of-a-nonnegative-symmetric-matrix-with-zero-diagon

Answer (score 0):

@5xum already gave a complete answer, but there is another quite intuitive/graphical solution, that I'd like to share.

Given a complex-valued matrix $A∈ℂ^{n×n}$. We define the Gershgorin circle discs $G_{r_i}(a_{ii})$ with midpoint $a_{ii}$ and radius
$$r_i = \sum_{k=1 \\ k\neq i}^n |a_{ik}|.$$

Then the *Gershgorin circle theorem* states: 

Every eigenvalue of $A$ lies within one of the Gershgorin discs.

Additionally it holds if $m$ circles intersect, then $m$ eigenvalues are located somewhere in the union of these $m$ circles.

With that theorem it is easy to construct a counter example, where all eigenvalues are on the right half of the complex domain. For example the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}42 & 1 \\ 1 & 42\end{pmatrix}$$
has the two circles $G_1(42)$, so for both eigenvalues it is $Re(λ_{1,2})≥41$.