# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a nonnegative symmetric matrix with zero diagonal, is $-\lambda$ also an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ with $n\geq 2$, non-negative (i.e. no negative elements), symmetric matrix with zero diagonal, is it necessarily the case that the set of all eigenvalues of $A$ can be written $L=\{\pm\lambda_0,\pm\lambda_1,\cdots\}$?

Comment: I assume you want to have $n=2k$, so even numbers?

Comment: Not necessarily. I thought that the question was more interesting than it is, and that n=1 was the trivial case when it failed. However, if $n=2k$, is the answer to my question affirmative?

Comment: @Wapiti no, take the matrix of ones with a diagonal of zeroes, it has eigenvalues $-1$ and $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A simple counterexample:
$$
\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&1&0},
$$
whose eigenvalues are $2,-1,-1$.

Comment: Ohhhh, beaten by 22 seconds!

Comment: @5xum That's why `\pmatrix{}` is superior to `\begin{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}`.

Comment: No no I used `\begin{bmatrix}`, I just thought you said I used actual `[` and `]` signs

Comment: @5xum Ha ha, `\pmatrix{}` rules then.

Answer (score 3):

No, take $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

which has eigenvalues $-1$ and $2$.